# Career CV edit: "Where do you want to work" is not saving the preferred locations

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When editing your CV, under *Job status*, there's an option to add cities, states or zip codes on where you would like to relocate.

I tried adding a few countries and clicked save. I noticed that the states are not getting saved. I tried a lot of variants to get it to work and nothing did -- It's simply not saving!

This is the part I'm talking about:

[image: Add a country part]

Answer (score 1):

Uh, a recent refactor had broken the "Save" behavior.

This is now fixed.

Thanks for your report!